# Why am I not making any progress toward the Research Assistant badge?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badge-progress

I have submitted several tag wiki edit suggestions, which have been approved.
From a quick look at my revisions history, there's [compression](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/3259/revisions), [sales](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/3235/revisions), [energy-efficiency](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/3181/revisions), [xwindow-x10](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/3074/revisions), [xwindow-x11](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/3076/revisions), [8088](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/2929/revisions), [punched-cards](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/2444/revisions) and [ibm-pc](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/1015/revisions). Several of these have also seen a fair amount of use, and several (but I don't think all of them) are ones I created. (A rule of thumb for me is to never create a new tag if I can't think of a reasonable tag wiki excerpt that summarizes its intended use. Of course, I try to remember to come back after the edit is approved, if applicable, to actually propose the tag wiki excerpt too!)

Certainly [ibm-pc](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibm-pc) is an old one by now; I created that one by adding it to [a question of my own a year ago](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/955/3), and [the initial tag wiki was approved around that same time](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/1015/2).

Even so, on my profile, *Research Assistant* ("edit 50 tag wikis") still shows the progress as 0/50.

What's up with that?

Comment: I got caught by this one - over the course of three days when I had some spare time I went through two and a half pages of tags, editing the tag wiki excerpts where they were _slightly_ less clear than they could be. It did encourage me to make more edits though, so there is a plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Research Assistant badge is awarded for editing tag wiki *bodies*.  Edits of the Usage Guidance don't count.  This is a common question, the badge list [on the site](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges) doesn't make this clear.

Looking at your example of [ibm-pc](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibm-pc), I see in the edit history that you have edited the guidance (and Wizzwizz4 approved it in review on June 25th 2016) but that there is no body.

To quote from the Main Meta:
[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/236563)

> **Research Assistant**
>
> silver;
>    awarded once
>    Edit 50 different tag wiki bodies
>    You can edit an
>   existing tag wiki or create a new one
>    Edits to tag wiki excerpts do
>   not count (source)

The referenced source is to a much older Main Meta post:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/236563

Compared to most sites, I believe we are pretty good at completing the tag wikis.  Please everyone keep the wiki edits coming, and you get the 2 points of reputation for each of the body and the excerpt.